# Is there a name for this sort-of-inverse function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inverse-function, relation-algebra

I'm looking for the mathematical name of a particular function which is available in several functional programming languages.

If $f$ is a function $f:X\to Y$, then define $g : Y \to 2^X$ as follows.

$g(y) = \{x \in X \mid f(x) = y\}$

For example, if $f(0) = 1, f(1) = 2, f(2) = 1, f(3) = 3$, then $g(0) = \emptyset, g(1)=\{0,2\}, g(2) = \{1\}, g(3)=\{3\}$.

Comment: I would call $g$ the "set-valued inverse" or "multivalued inverse" of $f$.

Comment: I'm not a relational algebra expert, but isn't there an operator in relational algebra which performs this type of query?

Answer (score 1):

Well, given a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$. Define the relation
$$x\equiv x':\Longleftrightarrow f(x)=f(x').$$
This is an equivalence relation on $X$ and the equivalence class $\bar x = \{x'\in X\mid x\equiv x'\}$ of $x\in X$ is the fibre of $x$ w.r.t. $f$.

Then the function $g:Y\rightarrow 2^X$ is given by $g(y) = f^{-1}(y)$, where $f^{-1}(y)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)=y\}$ is the preimage of $y\in Y$ in $f$. This preimage is given by a fibre, i.e., if $f(x)=y$, then $f^{-1}(y) = \bar x$. Note that $g(y)=\emptyset$ if $y$ is not in the image of $f$.

Comment: So would it make sense to call $g$ the fiber of $f$?

Comment: Apparently in french, this function is called the antecedent.  Nice name.   In english, according to wikipedia, it is called the fiber as Wuestenfux suggested above.   https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antécédent_(mathématiques) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(mathematics)

Answer (score 1):

This is called the *preimage*, and is usually denoted by $f^{-1}$ (not to be confused with the inverse, which uses the same notation!). In this case you only look at the preimage of one element, but we often consider it for more general sets as well. That is, given $A \subseteq Y$ we have
$$
f^{-1}(A) = \{ x \in X : f(x) \in A \}.
$$
In the specific case you are interested in, $A$ is just a singleton every time.